# nodejs - saving a new file in relation to my filetree

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Creating a file with node fs works fine:

```
fs.writeFile('TEST.js', myVariable, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
    });
```

But I would like to save the file in my filetree with relation and not with the filesystem of the computer. Something like we do with `require(../folder0/folder1/script)`.

```
folder0
   here is my file after creation
folder1
   folder1_1
      folder1_1_1
         I need my file here
```

Is there any solution? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you share your folder structure? You can use `path` module to resolve the relative path.

Comment: folder structure added above

Comment: Do you have `folder1, folder1_1` etc... created already?

Comment: Everything is created :-). I only need to store a new file in an existing folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use combination of `__dirname` and `path.resolve` to make an absolute path out of relative path. Like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const relativePath = '../folder1/folder1_1/folder1_1_1/myfile.txt';
const absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, relativePath);
```

... then just use this path inside writeFile (or any other function of fs).

Note that in the case you've shown (when your current directory is folder0), you don't need to specify that folder in your relative path, `..` should be used instead to get out of this folder and go up the directory tree.